# Access div id within droppable

Tags: jquery

Can I access the div id of a droppable element within jQuery :

```
$(".all").droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
        // Get the droppable div id here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.id`, or get that from the `ui.helper`:

```
$( ".all" ).droppable({ 
  drop: function(event, ui) { 
    alert( ui.helper.id );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `drop` event `$(this)` represents the droppable element and `ui.draggable` represents the draggable. You can try this.

```
$(".all").droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```